# CRUD генератор для zend2 / zend1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-2, crud

Интересуют готовые модули-хелперы для Zend1 / Zend2 , для генерации админок. В идеале проект-пример где используется какой-то CRUD фреймворк совместно с ZF. Надоело велосипедить каждый раз с этими админками, тогда как в других фреймворках это уже в коробке есть.

Хотелось бы не редактор БД вроде phpmyadmin , а именно фреймворк - который для любой таблицы БД(или группы таблиц) даст универсальный бекенд, привелегии к которому можно регулировать кодом, а также валидаторы/фильтры полей, и стандартный фронтенд, который можно менять, менять отображение полей, делать видовые трансформации данных поля. И желательно посовременнее, вроде http://crudkit.com .

Существует ли такое в природе для зенда? Если да, то посоветуйте пожалуйста лучший. Если нет - может быть у кого-то был опыт впиливания, поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой на репу.

Простите за топик, к которому не может быть однозначного ответа - тем не менее ничего не нагуглил на данную тематику.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Zoeken :**

Для `ZF1`, вы можете использовать `Zoeken`, она предоставляет полные интерфейсы Crud. Для `ZF2` находится в разработке.

- https://code.google.com/p/zodeken/ (https://code.google.com/archive/p/zodeken/downloads)
- https://code.google.com/p/zodeken2/   (https://code.google.com/archive/p/zodeken2/downloads)

**Zend Framework Tool (ZFTool)**

Восможности :

- создать проект `ZF2`, установка скелета приложения
- создать новый модуль внутри существующего приложения `ZF2`
- получить список всех модулей, установленных внутри приложения
- получить файл конфигурации приложения `ZF2`
- установить библиотеку `ZF2` выбирая конкретную версию

Тут вам придется немного попотеть,документация хреновая (Может в дальнейшем улучшат) :).Eсть мощный пакет в **ZF2** для отражения кода, сканирования и генерации.

- http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/namespaces/Zend.Code.html
- https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendCode

Comment: Спасибо, Zoeken посмотрю. Но немного напрягает что по названию ничего не гуглится - не ожидаю чего-то качественного. Не знаю при чём тут ZFTool правда, он бесполезен, модуль я и ручками могу создать, а библиотеку/скелет/и.т.п composer-ом поставить)

Comment: это все что на данный момент есть . последний вариант это сесть и написать самому.
пытался дать исчерпывающий ответ чтобы больше не мучались гуглив.
Думаю если за Zoken серьезно возьмутся то может что то и получится.Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо. Судя по всему актуально написать модуль качественного гибкого CRUID для доктрины, встраеваемый в зенд. И денег заработать, и славу)) К сожалению времени нету, может быть у местных знатоков зенда будет!

Comment: @Гончаров Александр Да не говори, а может стоит Угробить полгода,А там глядишь и получится :)) .

Answer (score -1):

Вот что обнаружил - прекрасный портал https://zfmodules.com/?query=crud , где есть 700 модулей для Zend 2. В том числе там есть несколько реализаций CRUD